# Amazon S3 Bucket Backup

Tags: amazon-s3

I wanted to ask if there is a way to backed up an Amazon S3 Bucket on Standard Storage to an Amazon S3 RRS Redundant Storage Bucket in a different account directly without using a Server/Custom Script in between.

I know the storage has high redundancy but a second maintained copy would be an advantage and not have to use a server nightly etc would also be an advantage.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your files under a different user account, I think the only way is to write a custom script that uses the S3 API (for example in Python with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)).
However if you are looking for long-term durable storage, I would suggest to have a look at [Amazon Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/en/glacier/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Glacier is good option for chipper backup. But for that you have to use such tool which provide you enough description about the uploaded archive file because Glacier does not upload file as file name, it keep file in different alphanumeric name generated by it.
2. It will not replace your changed file by new one, it will upload new with old one.

So If you want to keep your data for long time and do not want to retrieve repeatedly then use it.

Amazon S3 STANDARD STORAGE KEEP YOUR DATA SAFE BUT EVEN YOU WANT TO HAVE BACKUP THEN YOU CAN USE ANY TOOL WHICH SUPPORTING COPY BETWEEN TWO BUCKET. AND THEN YOU CAN APPLY RRS STORAGE TYPE ON ALL THE OBJECTS OF THE BUCKET.

I am one of the developer of Bucket Explorer S3 Tool. You can use Bucket Explorer for copying your data between two difference bucket either in same or different aws account.
and also provide batch update metadata option to update RRS setting on the all existing files.

Thanks